# Magento 2 Should I use multiple require js inside a phtml file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I need to use require js to use jquery in my block.
Do I have to declare for each function require JS at each beginning or there is a way to declare it only once?

here is my code, thanks

my html

```
<div class="mainMenu">
    <div style="background-color: black;color: white;">
        <div onClick="openCategory(1)">MENU 1</div>
        <div onClick="openCategory(2)">MENU 2</div>
        <div onClick="openCategory(3)">MENU 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div onClick="openMainMenu()">
    OUVRIR MENU
</div>
```

SCRIPT inside phtml

```
<script>
    let menu
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://catfact.ninja/fact",
            context: document.body
        }).done(function(value) {
            menu = []
            menu.forEach(element => {
                $('.mainMenu').append("<div class='menuContainer menuNumber" + element.id + "'>" + element.name + "</div>")
            });
        });


    });
    function openMainMenu(){
        require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
            $('.mainMenu').show()
        });
    }
    function openCategory(categoryNumber){
        require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
            console.log($('.menuNumber' + categoryNumber).css("visibility", "visible"));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

no this is a not a good approach to use JS code logic in the PHTML file , since magento is all about extensibility for developers like us , you can try moving the JS files to the separate directory **view/frontend/web/js** by using either jquery widget or component etc by follow this link you may have an idea - h[ttps://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/custom/](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/custom/)

This way if any other developers wants to over-ride that JS file they can do so easily by using **mixins** or **map** **etc**.

Please do let me know if this answer fulfils your question or do you need the entire code to move this custom JS logic to a separate JS file or not, and do like as such motivates me to post more answers.

Comment: thanks, I modified the code yesterday to create a separate js file with js folder and requirejs-config.js
but my question was about the declaration of require('jquery'), can I used multiple time like that in a single file ?

Comment: Yes @kevinrichard you can in separate script tags in that same PHTML file.

Comment: ok , you can create a new answer with this information, that I will confiirm, or edit this answer

Comment: Hi @kevinrichard Can i know for what purpose are you asking the whole answer ? Do you mean the full JS file and why because you have already achieved it right ?